Can we Configure a React Native's custom form component' input field (which is also custom) from outside the Form component?
I've made a Form component for handling signup/login now i want to handle add details and add facts screen using this form component now the problem is that the input fields of both login/signup and details are different.
I thinking of passing custom Input component for both these screens for handling different inputs styles but again problem is the props which I'll be getting in those forms is available when i map an array of form fields, what should be the approach??
My Login screen
My Expected Details Screen`
My Forms Component
import {memo, useState} from 'react';
import {Controller, useForm} from 'react-hook-form';
import {
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import Input from './Input';
import {colors} from '../../constants/colors';
import Button from './Button';
import DatePickerComponent from './DatePickerComponent';

const Form = ({
  onAuthenticate,
  changeMode,
  formdata,
  notSignin = false,
  onAdd,
}) => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState(true);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: {errors},
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      // email: 'test@email.com',
      // password: 'pass123',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      confirmPassword: '',
      author: '',
      quote: '',
      fact: '',
      bio: '',
      description: '',
    },
  });

  const onPress = mode => {
    reset();
    changeMode(mode);
  };

  const onSubmit = data => {
    const {email, password} = data;

    onAuthenticate({email, password});
    reset();
  };

  const confirmHandler = date => {
    setDate(date);
  };

  const onAddHandler = data => {
    const {author, quote, fact, bio, description} = data;
    onAdd({
      author: author,
      quote: quote,
      fact: fact,
      bio: bio,
      description: description,
      date: date.toISOString().slice(0, 10),
    });
    reset();
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.root}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          {formdata?.map(item => (
            <>
              {item.name !== 'date' && (
                <Input
                  key={item.name}
                  Controller={Controller}
                  errors={errors}
                  item={item}
                  control={control}
                  forgot={item.name === 'password' ? true : false}
                />
              )}

              {item.name === 'date' && (
                <DatePickerComponent
                  key={item.name}
                  Controller={Controller}
                  errors={errors}
                  item={item}
                  control={control}
                  date={date}
                  onConfirm={confirmHandler}
                  setDate={setDate}
                />
              )}
            </>
          ))}

          <View style={styles.container}>
            {notSignin && (
              <Button
                additionalStyles={styles.additionalStyles}
                onPress={handleSubmit(onAddHandler)}>
                Add Facts
              </Button>
            )}
            {!notSignin && (
              <Button
                additionalStyles={styles.additionalStyles}
                onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                {formdata?.length === 2 ? 'Login' : 'Signup'}
              </Button>
            )}
            {/* <Button
              mode="light"
              additionalStyles={styles.additionalStyles}
              onPress={() => {
                reset();
              }}>
              Reset
            </Button> */}
          </View>

          {!notSignin && (
            <>
              {formdata?.length === 2 && (
                <Text
                  style={styles.register}
                  onPress={() => {
                    onPress('signup');
                  }}>
                  Register User
                </Text>
              )}
              {formdata?.length !== 2 && (
                <Text style={styles.register} onPress={() => onPress('login')}>
                  {' '}
                  Login{' '}
                </Text>
              )}
            </>
          )}
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
            <Text style={styles.register}>Forgot Password</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  formContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    marginTop: 80,
    width: '100%',
  },
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  additionalStyles: {
    // width: 120,
    // height: 50,
    marginVertical: 40,
  },
  register: {
    fontFamily: 'DMSansBold',
    marginTop: 30,
    color: colors.paleYellow,
    fontSize: 17,
  },
  container: {flexDirection: 'row'},
  login: {fontFamily: 'DMSansBold', color: 'black'},
  already: {fontFamily: 'DMSansRegular', color: colors.grey200},
  create: {fontFamily: 'DMSansBold', color: 'black'},
});

export default memo(Form);


My InputComponent for login/signup

import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Text,
  Pressable,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import {colors} from '../../constants/colors';

const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('screen');

const Input = ({
  Controller,
  control,
  item,
  errors,
  open = false,
  date = null,
}) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    setError(errors);
  }, [errors]);

  let borderColor = colors.paleYellow;
  let tintColor = colors.paleYellow;
  if (error[item?.name]) {
    borderColor = 'red';
    tintColor = 'red';
  }
  // console.log('date from date picker--', date?.toISOString().slice(0, 10));

  if (item?.name === 'date') {
    return (
      <Controller
        control={control}
        rules={item?.rules}
        render={({field: {}}) => (
          <View
            style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
            <Pressable
              onPress={open}
              style={[styles.container, {borderColor: borderColor}]}>
              <Image
                source={item.icon}
                style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
              <Text>{date?.toISOString().slice(0, 10)}</Text>
            </Pressable>

            {error[item.name] && (
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'red',
                  paddingHorizontal: 20,
                }}>
                {error[item.name]?.message}
              </Text>
            )}
          </View>
        )}
        name={item.name}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      rules={item?.rules}
      render={({field: {onChange, value}}) => (
        <View
          style={[{justifyContent: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'white'}]}>
          <View
            style={[
              {
                width: width * 0.73,
                marginVertical: 10,
                // padding: 5,
                height: height * 0.06,
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
              },
              {borderColor: borderColor},
            ]}>
            {/* <Image
              source={item.icon}
              style={{
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                marginHorizontal: 5,
                tintColor: tintColor,
              }}
              resizeMode="contain"
            /> */}
            <TextInput
              placeholderTextColor={error[item?.name] ? 'red' : colors.grey200}
              placeholder={item?.placeholder}
              style={{color: colors.black}}
              onChangeText={onChange}
              value={value}
            />
          </View>
          {error[item.name] && (
            <Text
              style={{
                color: 'red',
                paddingHorizontal: 20,
              }}>
              {error[item.name]?.message}
            </Text>
          )}
        </View>
      )}
      name={item.name}
    />
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  container: {
    width: width * 0.73,
    margin: 10,
    padding: 5,
    height: height * 0.06,
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default Input;


